# Adding sub nodes to networkx (with image)

Tags: python, graph, networkx, network-analysis

I would like to create a networkx graph that looks more or less like this, but I haven't been able to find a way for it to display the way I need. The large nodes and edges display fine, but I haven't been able to find how to add the small nodes. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`networkx.draw()` has an [optional argument](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html) `node_size`:

`node_size (scalar or array, optional (default=300)) – Size of nodes. If an array is specified it must be the same length as nodelist.`

If you want to draw nodes with various sizes, you should specify the array of sizes. You can also use some kind of list generator.

---

P.S. I don't recommend to use basic networkx drawing functional. There are many powerful visualization libraries better than networkx. Even [in networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html) you can find the same opinion. One can use [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (with various libraries) or [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/) for really HUGE graphs.